# Identity asp.net core 3.0 - IdentityDbContext not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

My app broke with the 3.0 release of .NET core with reference errors for `IdentityDbContext`.  I'm looking through documentation for Identity on core 3.0 but it implies that IdentityDbContext should be there.  It's the only error I'm getting with a couple `DbContext` errors.

I have a pretty simple API, no MVC views, just a data server that gives back JSON objects.  It's based on Identity so it has the users and roles and claims.  And it's starting to take advantage of that.  My main DbContext extends `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` but after switching target platform to 3.0 after the upgrade, it says it doesn't exist and gives me compile errors.  Has anyone run into this?  Am I missing something?  The migration and breaking changes pages don't seem to have anything addressing my issue.

DbContext looks like this:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore; <- this no longer works either
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; //<- this I had to download as a package
using App.Constants;
using App.Models.Identity;

namespace App.Models
{
    public class AppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> //<- error is right here
    {
        ... my models
    }
}
```

Comment: _IdentityDbContext should be there._ - but the [IdentityDBContext docs page is not available for net core 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-3?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0) - there is an option to [AddIdentityCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.addidentitycore?view=aspnetcore-3.0) though?

Comment: @stuartd - well I was reading through this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0 which just has it.  Given I was skimming through it to get the information I need from it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In **ASP.NET Core 3.0**, `Entity Framework Core` and `Identity` related packages have been removed from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage. So you have to add those packages separately.

Add the following `PackageReference`s to your project's `.csproj` file as follows:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now it will work!

For more details: [Assemblies removed from the ASP.NET Core shared framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-3.0#assemblies-removed-from-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework)

Comment: Well it appears to work. Thanks!  I'm not sure why that's not in the docs.  However now assigning `services.AutoMapper()` broke too so once I get that running and I can roll back my initial create migration and setup everything again with the change listed above, I'll mark yours as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks - this was needed for "Storing Identities in the Database" section of this Pluralsight course: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspnetcore-mvc-efcore-bootstrap-angular-web

Answer (score 2):

if you have an error like "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityDbContext' could not be found" 
     you can install bellow package for asp.net web api 3 project

dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore --version 5.0.0-preview.3.20215.14
     in dotnet cli.its work for me.

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 5.0.0-preview.3.20215.14
      this for package manager

Comment: This is the correct solutions, Thanks Pamal